# Как переопределить путь в backend Yii?

Tags: php, yii2

Недавно задавал вопрос по этой теме, но одну ошибку решил, появилась новая.

Не так давно переносил свой сайт с одного домена на другой на одном и том же хостинге. Тех. поддержка с помощью симлинков помогла запустить его. Теперь при открытии контроллера admin части, он ссылается на прежний домен summit. Из-за чего выкидывает ошибку неправильного namespace.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как переопределить этот путь: `/home/w/websho/summit.today/backend/controllers/CallbackController.php` ?

Искал в PHPStorm через Find in Path связь с доменом, нашлись только логи:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду премного благодарен, уже мучаюсь несколько дней :(

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена с помощью симлинка на директорию ~/web.

`/xxx.ru/public_html [0] $ ln -s /home/w/account/xxx.ru/backend/web/ admin`